# Removing/Replacing a multiple words in a streamreader string

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader

I have a file I am opening and reading. In this file I have a few key words that I am replacing with different DB stuff.

My problem: I need to be able to REMOVE specific text from the read file. More than just one word. Nothing I have tried works. The .Remove method returns and empty file after I'm done with it. Here is my reader code

```
   using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"\\GTU-FS02\ScanTests\RLA.htm"))
   {

      /* Commented out. TRIED, but does not work
      string fill = reader.ReadToEnd();
      string toRemove = "GTU Renewal Application (a shorter, simplified renewal form)";
      int i = fill.IndexOf(toRemove);
      if (i > 1)
      {
          fill.Remove(i, toRemove.Length);
      }    
      */
      string toRemove = "GTU Renewal Application (a shorter, simplified renewal form)";
      string fill = reader.ReadToEnd();
      string fill2 = null;
      if (fill.Contains(toRemove))
      {
           fill2 = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("UWNAME", UW).Replace("ClientFName", subFname).Replace("ExDate", ExpDate).Replace("UwEmail", UwEmail(UW))
                     .Replace("CinSured", client).Replace("&amp;", amperSand).Replace(toRemove, "");

      }
      line = fill2;
  }
```

What you're seeing is different attempts at solving this. I can easily find what I'm looking for, but I can't remove or replace the text. The text will always be the same, so I know I can look for it that way. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the content in the file?  e.g. saving the changes back to that file?

Comment: did you try to debug and find out the value for fill2 variable

Comment: Amy, I am trying to remove that text assigned to the string variable "string toRemove". I then write that new text to an email body

Answer (score 0):

The first approach (the commented one) doesn't work for the simple reason that strings are immutable objects. The Remove method returns a new string, doesn't change the string that call the method. So your code should be simply fixed with

```
  line = fill.Remove(i, toRemove.Length);
```

the second approach doesn't work because you have called ReadToEnd two times. So the second time the stream is already to the end of the file and cannot read anything in the fill2 variable. Just remove the first ReadToEnd and then get the result of the Replace calls. (Again strings are immutable and all string methods perform their task and return a new string without changing the calling string)

```
  string toRemove = "GTU Renewal Application (a shorter, simplified renewal form)";
  string fill = reader.ReadToEnd();
  if (fill.Contains(toRemove))
  {
       line = fill.Replace("UWNAME", UW)
                  .Replace("ClientFName", subFname)
                  .Replace("ExDate", ExpDate)
                  .Replace("UwEmail", UwEmail(UW))
                  .Replace("CinSured", client)
                  .Replace("&amp;", amperSand)
                  .Replace(toRemove, "");

  }
```

Comment: Remove the last line in the code, that makes the replacement somewhat useless. Or change 'line' into fill2 inside the if statement.

Comment: Consider using `StringBuilder.Replace` (rather than `string.Replace`) if you are doing more than a handful of replacements.  Create the StringBuilder from the string, and then call Replace all you want.  It will do the replacements within the StringBuilder's buffer, rather than creating a new string each time.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Unfortunately, those don't work either. I've tried them prior, but for your help's sake, I did again. Your second method returns empty.. the first causes errors. I tried it multiple ways and it just doesn't work. It seems silly that simply removing a predefined set of text is so difficult

Comment: Flydog57. Any example how to implement that? I look up StringBuilder, but didn't how it was implement differently

Comment: I think you need to start the debugger then. Put a breakpoint on the line that call ReadToEnd and check what is the result from that method. Then proceed step by step and observe the changes in your variables

Answer (score 0):

I tried that and it works.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/lxtVGN

Check what the `reader.ReadToEnd();`
are returning,

Do not initialize a string with null, always initialize it with `""` or `String.Empty`

Comment: Marcos, I've tried both "" and String.Empty. I sadly get the same results no matter which way I choose. I can achieve the same results you are in this solution, but something goes haywire when I read from a file versus the instantiated string. Like in your example. I haven't figured that part yet.

Comment: can you provide an example file to run a test?